# XCode doesn't recognize UI Class UITextChecker

Tags: iphone, uikit, uitextfield

I am writing an app for my iPad running 3.2.2 with XCode 3.2.3.  It seems that the highest version of the iOS for iPad this version of XCode has is 3.2, but other apps load fine onto the phone so this doesn't seem to be an issue.  I am attempting to make use of the new UITextChecker class.  I have imported UIKit, and UITextChecker.h appears in the headers folder under the UIKit.framework icon.  However, when I try to compile this code:

```
NSString *theLanguage = [[UITextChecker availableLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

or simply this:

```
UITextChecker *textChecker;
```

XCode tells me that UITextChecker is undeclared.  Any ideas what it going on here?  Thanks!

James

Here is a picture of the UIViewController's header file:
[image]

Comment: I think we need to see more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For whatever reason, UIKit.h does not import UITextChecker.h. You can fix this by also adding the following line.

```
#import <UIKit/UITextChecker.h>
```